# Android | Custom style as parent for another custom style

Tags: android, xamarin, resources, styles, xamarin.android

Hi I am new to Android is it possible in Android to make your own defined style as parent of another style?

```
      <style name="style1">
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </style>
      <style name="extendedStyle1" parent="@style/style1">
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </style>
```

Comment: Thanks could you please write an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found an answer, Thanks to everybody.

```
     <style name="style1">
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </style>
      <style name="style1.extended">
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </style>
```